Is 'retractor' the correct name for this device?
Background: (English is not my native language) I'm looking for a small device with a line that can be extended from a base.
But with the property that when pulled slowly it just extends but when suddenly pulled fast it locks. Just like the automatic seatbelts in cars.
Looking up what this system is called I found it is called 'a retractor'.
However, when looking for something like this on the web, I find things that look like 'normal' key chains that do have a string, but it just roll in and out with no blocking at all in the regard of the speed.
So my question is: Is 'retractor' not the correct term for a device doing what I need?
And if not, what do you call a device like that?

device with a line that can be extended? Do you mean a retractable tape measure? Or something else? Or other devices with in-built retractors? Could you please clarify your question.

You need to be more specific than just retractor. An inertia reel or inertia locking retractor or similar is the usual term for the part in a seatbelt: this refers to the way that a hard pull locks it and a soft pull lets it come out. Similar devices are also used when working at height to catch you when you fall suddenly while allowing a cable to be gradually unspooled (inertia reel lifelines or fall arrestors). The Wikipedia article seat belt has more information.
Examples:

Inertia reel fall arrestors, Start Safety (UK company): "These blocks act a lot like a seatbelt in terms of how they operate; they can feed out either a cord or strap to which you are anchored; if you fall, the mechanism quickly locks, preventing you from travelling any further."
Self-retracting lifelines or “inertia reels” for fall protection, Stop Save (UK company)
2 point Inertia seatbelt retractor white seatbelt component in Volkswagen parts shop
Seatbelts with inertia retraction, Mazda MX-5 owners forum, UK.
Inertia Reels/Fall Arrest Blocks, Rams Lifting Gear, UK
Inertia Locking Retractor, Seat Belts Plus, Arizona, USA
Retractable Seat Belt, Inertia Reel, Moss Motors, USA


Thank you. I used your additional information to find and get one. Thanks again.

A retractor retracts something, i.e. it is used to pull something back in (or perhaps back out). The locking feature that you are asking about is sometimes found on retractors, but its presence is not implied by the name. When a locking feature is present it may stop a seat belt pulling out quickly, to protect a car occupant. Or it may stop a garden hose from retracting quickly, so that slow retraction allows the entire hose to be retracted.
